# UIButton does not remove target for UIControlEventtouchDragInside

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, target

having some problems with removing targets from UIButton. Basically I have a calendar and want to be able to move a button representing an event saved in the calendar around. I start with:

> ```
> [self.chosenButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragMoving:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
> ```

and then after the moving is done I call

> ```
> [self.chosenButton removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
> ```

After that, however, I can still move the button around even though it should remain still. In the dragMoving:withEvent: function I only assign the coordinates of the button depending on the touch point and check its validity (if it is within the screen, etc.)

Any idea why is the dragMoving:WithEvent still being called?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because you actually do not remove target, try:

```
[self.chosenButton removeTarget:self  action:@selector(dragMoving:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work either. On posts around here people suggested that the way I'm trying now is the correct way to go, and it says so even in the Apple documentation, but unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Even this doesn't work? [self.chosenButton removeTarget:nil 
                   action:NULL 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

Comment: Tried that one as well, but not even that one.

Comment: Maybe share the code you create the button, bacause this must work.

Comment: The class where I do it has over 1500 lines, and the button is created and edited all over, so it is impossible to actually put here all of it. I was checking all the bits where the button was created, but it seems like it should be working the way it is.

Comment: make some test, may be, for example [self.chosenButton addTarget:nil action:nilforControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];, or may be the pointer to your chosenButton is nil and it does nothing.

Comment: Well adding nil nil TouchDragInside doesn't do anything, and I am sure the pointer is not a nil because right after I remove the TouchDrag I add an openDetails: target for touchUpInside which works perfectly fine.